# Will convert_timezone 'America/New_York' work regardless of my timezone's offset depending on time of year?

Tags: timezone, amazon-redshift, timezone-offset

My timezone is -4 or -5 from GMT depending on time of year. Currently it is -4.

If I use this code below, will it automatically switch when we change to -5?

```
select convert_timezone('America/New_York', CAST(json_extract_path_text('{"timestamp":"2019-04-16T03:30:00.704Z"}', 'timestamp') as TIMESTAMP));
```

Currently the line above returns a date of 2019-04-15.

But if I make this call in December (note the time has +1 hour), 
will it still return a date of 2019-04-15.

```
select convert_timezone('America/New_York', CAST(json_extract_path_text('{"timestamp":"2019-04-16T04:30:00.704Z"}', 'timestamp') as TIMESTAMP));
```

In other words, will it switch between EDT and EST without intervention? Or is there a better way?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider:

- `2019-04-16T03:30:00.704Z` (UTC) in `America/New_York` is `2019-04-15T23:30:00.704-04:00`
- `2019-04-16T04:30:00.704Z` (UTC) in `America/New_York` is `2019-04-16T00:30:00.704-04:00`
- `2019-12-16T04:30:00.704Z` (UTC) in `America/New_York` is `2019-12-15T23:30:00.704-05:00`

For US Eastern Time, a date in April will be in -4 while a date in December will be in -5.  In other words, the timestamp being converted is what determines which offset to apply.

***The date and time that the code executes has no relevance***.